# R glm multivariate syntax shorter

Tags: r, dataframe, glm

I have an example data.

`DF<- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                   y1=c(1,2,3,4,8,8,4),
                   y2=c(12,11,5,7,4,7,8),
                   y3=c(2,3,4,5,3,2,1))`

```
DF1 <- glm(DF$y1 ~ -1 + factor(DF$x))
DF2 <- glm(DF$y2 ~ -1 + factor(DF$x))
DF3 <- glm(DF$y3 ~ -1 + factor(DF$x))
result <- cbind(DF1$res, DF2$res, DF3$res)
```

Can you help how I can glm model syntax take shorter?

Answer (score 1):

Since a GLM with `family = gaussian` is just ordinary linear regression:

```
fit <- lm(cbind(y1,y2,y3) ~ -1 + factor(x), data=DF)
result <- fit$res
```